# How to dynamically insert an orderby statement in a query array

Tags: php, sql-order-by

I'm trying to dynamically assign the sort order (stored in $current_sort below) for a query that lists menu items.

If I hard code the sort order it works fine, however, when I try to dynamically assign the sort parameters to a string, it fails. What am I missing?

```
$current_sort = ", 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'asc'";
$myposts = get_posts(
    array(
        'cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden",
        'numberposts' => $my_current_count . $current_sort
        ));

//If I hard code the value of $current_sort it works fine
$myposts = get_posts(
    array(
        'cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden",
        'numberposts' => $my_current_count,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'asc'));
```

Comment: How is one approach dynamic while the other is not? There's nothing preventing you from writing `'orderby' => $sortField`. And it shouldn't be that difficult to isolate the field name and sort direction from whatever it is inside `$currentSort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot turn a string into PHP source code. (At least you *shouldn't*.)

Try this:

```
$current_sort_order = "title";
$current_sort_direction = "asc";

$myposts = get_posts(array(
      'cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden",
      'numberposts' => $my_current_count,
      'orderby' => $current_sort_order,
      'order' => $current_sort_direction
      )             );
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong, you don't have to concate..try this:

$current_sort = "title";
$order = "asc";
$myposts = get_posts(
    array(
        'cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden",
        'numberposts' => $my_current_count,
        'orderby'=> $current_sort,
        'order' => $order
        ));

Answer (score 0):

The string concatenation on the line

```
'numberposts' => $my_current_count . $current_sort
```

is not equivalent to creating multiple array elements as in

```
'numberposts' => $my_current_count,
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'asc'));
```

In the first instance, `numberposts` becomes a string containing information about the sort.
In the second instance, `numberposts` only contains the current count.

A better option may be:

```
$orderoption="<TITLE HERE>";
$order_dir="<SORT OPTION HERE>";
$myposts = get_posts(
array(
    'cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden",
    'numberposts' => $my_current_count,
    'orderby' => $orderoption,
    'order' => $order_dir));
```